# How to use SVN to diff an entire repository (preferably with Tortoise SVN)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, repository

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a diff of a repository that you've checked out and save it to a diff file so that you can contribute it to a project as a full patch. I'm using Tortoise SVN, but if it has to be at the command line, that's OK too.

Comment: A diff between repository and what?

Comment: @Ha The checked out version. Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click the root directory of your working folder, and select **TortoiseSVN/Create Patch...**

Answer (score 3):

You can compare two revisions using the [svn diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) command, but you'll need the SVN binaries for that purpose.

With TortoiseSVN, you can simply open up the "Show log" dialog, select two revisions, right-click and click on "Show differences as unified diff" - you can then save that diff file. If you only want to have a diff between your working copy and the checked-out revision, you can also use the "Create patch" feature.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about doing it with tortoise, but in a CLI it would be:

```
svn diff directory
```

And to save it to a file you would just redirect the output

```
svn diff directory > my-patch.diff
```

Comment: @Yuppie +1 Thanks. I'll download and try this with the Subversion binary sometime.